# Is there an algorithm for determining if given sentence is a sub-sentence of a grammar?

Tags: algorithm, parsing

For example, given the grammar

```
Expr -> Number | Number '+' Expr
Number -> [1-9][0-9]*
```

we see that for `+ 1` there exists a sentence (e.g. `1 + 1`) which is parsed by the grammar and for which `+ 1` is sub-sentence. Is there a general algorithm for this? I think that if we can put some kind of flags in the parser we should be able to tell it to skip some initial and some final tokens while parsing but I'm not sure whether this would work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you transform the grammar into an automaton, possible subsentences are sequences with an arbitrary start node and arbitrary end node. For non-derterministic automatons this is probably in NP. It should be easier for deterministic automatons. However, creating a deterministic one is hard.

Comment: +1 to @NicoSchertler. As a naive approach you could probably take each state of the automaton as a possible starting point, feed it the subsequence and ensure that after each character you end up in a state that can accept the next character. If no starting state exists where that is possible, the sequence is not a valid subsequence.

Comment: @NicoSchertler NP includes P, so that doesn't say much. I assume you meant NP-complete, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:P_np_np-complete_np-hard.svg).

Comment: @NicoSchertler For a PDA, you'd need to guess the contents of the stack as well, probably via dynamic programming for efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but this argument shows that the class of context-free languages is closed under this operation via a linear-time transformation of a Chomsky normal form grammar.

The idea is to introduce, for each nonterminal symbol A, three other symbols Apre, Asuf, Asub, which match prefixes, suffixes, and substrings of strings matched by A.

For transitions A -> s, add

```
Apre ->
Apre -> s
Asuf ->
Asuf -> s
Asub ->
Asub -> s.
```

For transitions A -> B C, add

```
Apre -> Bpre
Apre -> B Cpre
Asuf -> Csuf
Asuf -> Bsuf C
Asub -> Bsub
Asub -> Csub
Asub -> Bsuf Cpre.
```

Change the start symbol from S to Ssub.